# Reform matrix from a 2D logical matrix (without reshaping)

Tags: matlab, matrix, boolean

I tried to rebuild the matrix from the logical arguments as in the example below:

```
a=rand(2,5)
b=rand(2,5)
c=a>b

a(:,c)=b(:,c)
```

However I get `Index exceeds matrix dimension` error. Can this be done without reshaping the matrix beforehand?

Comment: To me it seems like you wanted to do `a(c) = b(c)`. If you provide non-random exact inputs alongwith the expected output for those inputs, your question would be clearer than it currently is

Answer (score 0):

If you want to copy the least value between, `a` and `b` into a for each entry try:

```
a=rand(2,5);
b=rand(2,5);


c = find(a>b); % c contains the position of value of the greatest val
a(c)=b(c)  % removes greates value copying a smaller value from b
```

If you want to copy the greatest value modify the statement creating variable `c`.

`Index exceeds matrix dimensions` is caused by you trying to use as matrix dimensions a list `:` and a matrix `c`. Find creates a list of values which satisfy the relationship wanted and can be used to recall specific values.